# Best way implement destructor in JS

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

Consider the code below

```
class Hello {
    constructor(name) {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            console.log('===', name)
        }, 1000)
    }
    destroy() {
        clearInterval(this.interval)
    }
}
let h = new Hello('aaa')
// h.destory()
h = new Hello('bbb')
```

If the constructor allocate some resource, where to release the resource?
As far as I current understanding, when `h` is re-assigned to `new Hello('bbb')` to memory holding `new Hello('aaa')` should be released by GC .

Is this a good convention that `new` and `destroy` should come in pair?

Comment: @MaheerAli  destroy is the way come up with to handle the "reassignment" problem, what is the better to handle this case

Comment: Clearing an interval or a timeout is probably one of the very few cases in which you would want to have this type of destructor-like functionality. Destructors are not a common pattern in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way (i believe) to catch the garbage collection of an object to perform some action. Instead you need to build your own management for cleaning up resources like timers, etc. by making your creations/removals explicit. I know your example is a toy, but you can't simply reallocate in the way you have shown. You need to do something like:

```
const objects = {}

const createObject = name => {
  const obj = new Hello(name)
  objects[name] = obj
  return obj
}

const deleteObject = name => {
  objects[name].destroy()
  delete objects[name]
}

let h = createObject('aaa')
deleteObject('aaa') // interval cleared but not gc'd because of h
h = createObject('bbb') // all references to aaa now gone
```

Obviously this is a simple example, and there will be more elegant ways to do it depending on your needs, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Downvoted with no comment? Ready to learn something if you'll share your knowledge.

Comment: Maybe my question is not a one explicitly asking for a answer to a specific problem

Comment: Well you have `where to release the resource?` in your question. I am explaining that you need to manage this stuff yourself, and given you one example where cleanup is explicit and coupled to `destroy`.

Comment: It's a toy example. The point here is that if you want management you should use and stick to an api that couples the underlying requirements for cleaning up your things. You could say *this won't work if you don't use it correctly* for just about anything in js. If you have a better proposal/explanation I would really like to learn.